# max zoom in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to set maximum zoom level to block the possibility of zooming after some point in my map.

```
var mapa; // obiekt globalny

function dodajMarker(opcjeMarkera)
{
    opcjeMarkera.map = mapa;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(opcjeMarkera);
}

function mapaStart()  
{  
    var wspolrzedne = new google.maps.LatLng(65.080267,13.272461);
    var opcjeMapy = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: wspolrzedne,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        navigationControl: true, // kontrolka nawigacji
        navigationControlOptions:
        {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
        }
    };


    mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), opcjeMapy);

    // wspólne cechy ikon
    var rozmiar = new google.maps.Size(32,32);
    var rozmiar_cien = new google.maps.Size(59,32);
    var punkt_startowy = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
    var punkt_zaczepienia = new google.maps.Point(16,16);

    // ikonki
    var ikona1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker1.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona2 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker2.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona3 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker3.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona4 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker4.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona5 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker5.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona6 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker6.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona7 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker7.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona8 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker8.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona9 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker9.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona10 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker10.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona11 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker11.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona12 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker12.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona13 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker13.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona14 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker14.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona15 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker15.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona16 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker16.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona17 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker17.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);
    var ikona18 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("markers/marker18.png", rozmiar, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);

    var cien1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/shadow50.png", rozmiar_cien, punkt_startowy, punkt_zaczepienia);

    function dodajMarker(opcjeMarkera)
    {
        opcjeMarkera.map = mapa;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(opcjeMarkera);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            window.location.href = marker.url;
        });

    }

    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(66.769332,13.33992), icon: ikona1, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/01/lowiskoNorwegiaArnoy.php', title: 'Wyspa Arnoy'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(69.570212,18.114624), icon: ikona2, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/02/lowiskoNorwegiaBuvik.php', title: 'Rejon Buvik'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(66.388821,13.127746), icon: ikona3, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/03/lowiskoNorwegiaPolarsikelen.php', title: 'Rejon Koła Polarnego'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(61.850513,5.049362), icon: ikona4, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/04/lowiskoNorwegiaBakkevik.php', title: 'Rejon Bakkevik'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(70.101699,20.444641), icon: ikona5, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/05/lowiskoNorwegiaLyngenfjord.php', title: 'Rejon Lyngenfjord'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(65.663482,11.924744), icon: ikona6, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/06/lowiskoNorwegiaVega.php', title: 'Wyspa Vega'});

    //dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.203148,16.601637), icon: ikona7, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/07/lowiskoNorwegiaVansjon.php', title: 'Jezioro Vansjøn'});
    //dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.203148,16.601637), icon: ikona8, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/08/lowiskoNorwegiaVannoya.php', title: 'Wyspa Vannøya'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(69.679548,20.262508), icon: ikona9, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/09/lowiskoNorwegiaKoppangen.php', title: 'Koppangen'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(70.276422,21.532745), icon: ikona10, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/10/lowiskoNorwegiaLoppa.php', title: 'Półwysep Loppa'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(70.483098,23.17749), icon: ikona11, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/11/lowiskoNorwegiaSeiland.php', title: 'Wyspa Seiland'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(69.679548,20.262508), icon: ikona12, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/12/lowiskoNorwegiaStoralee.php', title: 'Jezioro Stora Lee'});

    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.244105,9.621048), icon: ikona13, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/13/lowiskoNorwegiaKroderen.php', title: 'Jezioro Krøderen'});
    //dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.203148,16.601637), icon: ikona14, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/14/lowiskoNorwegiaSperillen.php', title: 'Jezioro Sperillen'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(61.850513,5.049362), icon: ikona15, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/15/lowiskoNorwegiaAldersund.php', title: 'Wyspa Aldersund'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(69.320842,17.54425), icon: ikona16, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/16/lowiskoNorwegiaSenja.php', title: 'Wyspa Senja'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(67.740893,14.799929), icon: ikona17, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/17/lowiskoNorwegiaHelnessund.php', title: 'Rejon Helnessund'});
    dodajMarker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(58.941565,11.659999), icon: ikona18, shadow: cien1, url:'kraje/norwegia/18/lowiskoNorwegiaKornsjo.php', title: 'Jezioro Kornsjø'});
}
```

Comment: Maximum zoom level in what sense? So that all markers will be visible?

Comment: to block the possibility of zooming after some point

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The map has a property `maxZoom`. Simply set this to your value when you create your map.

Comment: You need also to add in html file where map is: options="device.map1.options"

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you should also check [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/) for details. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.maxZoom) is what Kasper mentioned.

So you will get quicker answers to your questions.

Powodzenia :).

Comment: Hehe Stackoverflow would have under half the number of posts if people actually read the API or documentation before asking ^^